# Odd warning when splitting lines at EOL markers

Tags: regex, perl

When I run the following code, I get my expected output - four individual lines.  When I uncomment the `use warnings` line, I get a message printed out:

> Unrecognized escape `\R` passed through at `./regex.pl` line 13.

What does this mean?  I haven't found much while googling that message yet the program seems to work (in other words, the escape `\R` IS recognized).

I'm using Perl 5.8.8

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
#use warnings;

my $txt = <<EOF;
dddddddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
ffffffffffffffff
gggggggggggggggg
EOF

my @tarr = split(/\R/, $txt);

foreach my $t (@tarr )
{
    print $t . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\R` was introduced in Perl v5.10.

Therefore your script is not actually splitting the lines as you'd see if you put text around each "line" or simply counted the results in your array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $txt = <<'EOF';
dddddddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
ffffffffffffffff
gggggggggggggggg
EOF

foreach my $t (split /\R/, $txt ) {
    print "<$t>\n";
}
```

Output when run under Perl v5.8.9:

```
Unrecognized escape \R passed through at e.pl line 12.
<dddddddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
ffffffffffffffff
gggggggggggggggg
>
```

You can read about it in [perl5100delta #Regular-expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Regular-expressions)

> - Vertical and horizontal whitespace, and linebreak
>
>   Regular expressions now recognize the `\v` and `\h` escapes that match vertical and horizontal whitespace, respectively. `\V` and `\H` logically match their complements.
>
>   `\R` matches a generic linebreak, that is, vertical whitespace, plus the multi-character sequence `"\x0D\x0A"`.

Answer (score 0):

Special sequences in interpolated strings in perl - which includes regexps are marked by `\`

For instance `\n` is newline and `\t` is tab

`\R` doesn't represent anything special so perl is warning you

`\r` is a carriage return

**update: just checked perlrebackslash and apparently \R is "\R                Generic new line.  Not in []." in regexps**  Seems to be new in perl 5.10 so if your perl is older than that....check with `perl -v`